# How to split and iterate substrings by delimiter in BOURNE SHELL?

Tags: string, shell, loops, split, sh

Recently I've been trying to customize my shell profile located at `~/.profile` in Ubuntu. One thing I want to do is:

```
# PATH-like variable containing paths separated by ':'
MY_ROOTS=/f/o/o:/b/a/r:/e/t/c
for some magic iterating my_root in $MY_ROOTS do;
    my_bin="$my_root/bin"
    # add it to PATH!
    [ -d "$my_bin" ] && {
        expr ":$PATH:" : ".*:$my_bin:.*" >/dev/null || PATH="${PATH:+"$PATH:"}$my_bin"
    }
done
```

Since it's in .profile, I need the `iterating` part to be **Bourne Shell compatible**. Many people had asked some questions like this, but I believed that most those solutions looked like **Bashism**. After I spent a lot of time googling, I still hadn't found a suitable answer. May I have your advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sh
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=:
MY_ROOTS=/f/o/o:/b/a/r:/e/t/c
for my_root in $MY_ROOTS; do
    # your code here with $my_root
done
IFS="$OIFS"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it necessary to backup and restore IFS here?

Comment: Though the `set` can be replaced with `for my_root in $MY_ROOTS`. This is one of the few scenarios where the variable interpolation should not be in double quotes; you want the shell to perform token splitting on the value.

Comment: @tripleee I just read this [article](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#string_lists_in_for-loops) which said you should NOT double quote the variable here. Does sh behaves differently in any way? And thanks, considering use for...in instead of set as a good and simple practice.

Comment: Um, that's what I'm saying, too. "This is one of the few scenarios where the variable interpolation should **not** be in double quotes."

Comment: And may I ask a last question about the IFS? As I know the ANSI C like string is needed to set IFS to be some special charaters like <tab> and <newline>: `IFS=$'\t\n'`. So does double quote is already safe enough to do the backup-restore work here?

Comment: @tripleee you're right indeed, I have updated the answer as it is better as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @liz, yes, that's enough since you do not provide the "problematic" characters but they are already in a variable. You can check that by doing: `echo -n "$IFS" | hexdump -C` after restoring `IFS`.

Comment: @Pierre got it. I tested it for some cases and it worked well. So I guess this is the eventual solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's an extreme corner case, but it's worth being aware that if `IFS` was originally unset, then afterwards `IFS` is not unset but set to the empty string.

Comment: @chepner totally! As you mention, that's a corner case, but you're right.

Comment: @chepner I bow to your superior carefulness!